# Getting access to the own thread information (delphi)

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi

For debugging purposes, I am iterating the threads of my own application, and trying to report the thread times (looking for a rogue thread). When I iterate the threads, I get access denied if the `threadId = GetCurrentThreadId`.

Here's an example of code to demonstrate the problem (delphi):

```
  program Project9;

  {$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

  {$R *.res}

  uses
    Windows, System.SysUtils, TlHelp32;

  type
    TOpenThreadFunc = function(DesiredAccess: DWORD; InheritHandle: BOOL; ThreadID: DWORD): THandle; stdcall;
  var
    OpenThreadFunc: TOpenThreadFunc;

  function OpenThread(id : DWORD) : THandle;
  const
    THREAD_GET_CONTEXT       = $0008;
    THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION = $0040;
  var
    Kernel32Lib, ThreadHandle: THandle;
  begin
    Result := 0;
    if @OpenThreadFunc = nil then
    begin
      Kernel32Lib := GetModuleHandle(kernel32);
      OpenThreadFunc := GetProcAddress(Kernel32Lib, 'OpenThread');
    end;
    result := OpenThreadFunc(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, False, id);
  end;

  procedure dumpThreads;
  var
    SnapProcHandle: THandle;
    NextProc      : Boolean;
    TThreadEntry  : TThreadEntry32;
    Proceed       : Boolean;
    pid, tid : Cardinal;
    h : THandle;
  begin
    pid := GetCurrentProcessId;
    tid := GetCurrentThreadId;
    SnapProcHandle := CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0); //Takes a snapshot of the all threads
    Proceed := (SnapProcHandle <> INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
    if Proceed then
      try
        TThreadEntry.dwSize := SizeOf(TThreadEntry);
        NextProc := Thread32First(SnapProcHandle, TThreadEntry);//get the first Thread
        while NextProc do
        begin
          if TThreadEntry.th32OwnerProcessID = PID then //Check the owner Pid against the PID requested
          begin
            write('Thread '+inttostr(TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID));
            if (tid = TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID) then

            write(' (this thread)');
            h := OpenThread(TThreadEntry.th32ThreadID);
            if h <> 0 then
              try
                writeln(': open ok');
              finally
                CloseHandle(h);
              end
            else
              writeln(': '+SysErrorMessage(GetLastError));
          end;
          NextProc := Thread32Next(SnapProcHandle, TThreadEntry);//get the Next Thread
        end;
      finally
        CloseHandle(SnapProcHandle);//Close the Handle
      end;
  end;


  function DebugCtrlC(dwCtrlType : DWORD) :BOOL;
  begin
    writeln('ctrl-c');
    dumpThreads;
  end;

  var
    s : String;
  begin
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(@DebugCtrlC, true);
    try
      writeln('enter anything to see threads, ''x'' to exit. or press ctrl-c to see threads');
      repeat
        readln(s);
        if s <> '' then
          dumpThreads;
      until s = 'x';
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  end.
```

I get access denied for this thread when pressing ctrl-c - why can't the thread get a handle to itself, but it can for all the other threads in the process?

Comment: Normally a thread gets a handle to itself with DuplicateHandle - if a real handle is required. If not, GetCurrentThread. BTW, what's wrong with "windows.OpenThread"?

Comment: It depends on what your goal of this excercise is but you can view thread timings with Process Explorer from Sysinternals without having to write all this yourself.

Comment: It's going to run unattended on a server and dump information in the back ground so I can get a sense of where my server is before it destroys the VM (then I can't connect to it to run Process Explorer).

Comment: are your thread is impersonating ? only this can be a reason for access denied

Comment: I'm not impersonating. I don't know about the thread from the console host before it gets to me

Comment: "what's wrong with "windows.OpenThread" - there isn't one - I don't know why.

Comment: There is a lot of code here, much more than is necessary. A [mcve] is needed. Because what you claim to be true cannot readily be reproduced. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - no, i check - really reproduced, if call `OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, GetCurrentThreadId());` from [`HandlerRoutine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) because this thread have `System Mandatory Level` integrity. of course can be created real minimal and complete example

Comment: @RbMm You can reproduce if you use information in comments and the answer. But not in the question. You have to understand that SO isn't a transient problem solving service for the asker, but a resource of Q&A topics. This is a good question once an [mcve] is provided, but as it stands it is not useful to future visitors.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - yes, based on information in answer that code called from `ctrl+c` handler. of course need rewrite question. not need any `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` etc. simply call `SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, TRUE);` and `OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, GetCurrentThreadId());` from `HandlerRoutine`. but really interesting that this new created thread (`CtrlRoutine`) have system integrity level, which prevent this thread from open

Comment: I assume it prevents you because they really want this thread to kill the process without 3rd-party code injecting itself and causing issues.

Comment: @Grahame - didn't know that, thanks. Should have been forgotten. And no one have noticed/bothered for more than 20 years. Can't find any explanation other than that.

Comment: @Anders - not view big sense use `S-1-16-16384` (*System Mandatory Level*)  label in this thread label (in security descriptor). despite `OpenThread` failed, we can open it handle with full access via `DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(), GetCurrentProcess(), &hThread, 0, 0, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);` . and in most case `GetCurrentThread()` (-2) also enough

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - interesting, but you correct from begin - `DuplicateHandle` always ok for current thread, despite thread SD, token, etc. when `OpenThread` can fail. even after call `ZwImpersonateAnonymousToken(GetCurrentThread())` for example - `DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(), GetCurrentProcess(), &hThread, 0, 0, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);` is ok

Comment: ok. updated the code for David Heffernan.

Comment: It's better, but there's still more code than needed. You don't need to enumerate threads, you just need to call `OpenThread` in the handler proc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

are some kernel object can be opened, based on 2 things:

- object security descriptor
- caller token (thread token if exist, otherwise process token)

usually thread can open self handle, but can be exceptions, one is - thread created by system, for handle console control signals.

minimum code for reproduce (*c++*):

```
HANDLE g_hEvent;

BOOL WINAPI HandlerRoutine(DWORD dwCtrlType)
{
    if (CTRL_C_EVENT == dwCtrlType)
    {
        if (HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, 
            FALSE, GetCurrentThreadId()))
        {
            CloseHandle(hThread);
        }
        else GetLastError();

        SetEvent(g_hEvent);
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

and from console application call

```
if (g_hEvent = CreateEvent(0, TRUE, FALSE, 0))
{
    if (SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, TRUE))
    {
      // send ctrl+c, for not manually do this
        if (GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent (CTRL_C_EVENT, 0))
        {
            WaitForSingleObject(g_hEvent, INFINITE);
        }
        SetConsoleCtrlHandler(HandlerRoutine, FALSE);
    }
    CloseHandle(g_hEvent);
}
```

can in test view that 
`OpenThread(THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION, FALSE, GetCurrentThreadId())` failed with error - `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`

why this happen ? need look for thread security descriptor. the simply code for this can look like:

```
void DumpObjectSD(HANDLE hObject = GetCurrentThread())
{
    ULONG cb = 0, rcb = 0x40;

    static volatile UCHAR guz;
    PVOID stack = alloca(guz);

    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR psd = 0;

    do 
    {
        if (cb < rcb)
        {
            cb = RtlPointerToOffset(psd = alloca(rcb - cb), stack);
        }

        if (GetKernelObjectSecurity(hObject, 
            OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION|DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION|LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            psd, cb, &rcb))
        {
            PWSTR sz;
            if (ConvertSecurityDescriptorToStringSecurityDescriptor(psd, SDDL_REVISION_1, 
                OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION|DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION|LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, &sz, &rcb))
            {
                DbgPrint("%S\n", sz);
                LocalFree(sz);
            }

            break;
        }

    } while (GetLastError() == ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
}
```

and call this from console handler thread and from usual (first thread) for compare.

the *SD* of usual process thread can look like:

for not elevated process:

```
O:S-1-5-21-*
D:(A;;0x1fffff;;;S-1-5-21-*)(A;;0x1fffff;;;SY)(A;;0x121848;;;S-1-5-5-0-LogonSessionId)
S:AI(ML;;NWNR;;;ME)
```

or for elevated ( running as admin)

```
O:BA
D:(A;;0x1fffff;;;BA)(A;;0x1fffff;;;SY)(A;;0x121848;;;S-1-5-5-0-LogonSessionId)
S:AI(ML;;NWNR;;;HI)
```

but when this called from handler thread (auto created by system) - we got another dacl:

for not elevated:

```
O:BA
D:(A;;0x1fffff;;;S-1-5-21-*)(A;;0x1fffff;;;SY)(A;;0x121848;;;S-1-5-5-0-LogonSessionId)
S:AI(ML;;NWNR;;;SI)
```

for elevated:

```
O:BA
D:(A;;0x1fffff;;;BA)(A;;0x1fffff;;;SY)(A;;0x121848;;;S-1-5-5-0-LogonSessionId)
S:AI(ML;;NWNR;;;SI)
```

different here in [`SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374928(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
S:AI(ML;;NWNR;;;SI)
```

the **`"ML"`** here is `SDDL_MANDATORY_LABEL` (`SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_ACE_TYPE`)

Mandatory label rights:

**`"NW"`** - `SDDL_NO_WRITE_UP` (`SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_WRITE_UP`)

**`"NR"`** - `SDDL_NO_READ_UP` ( `SYSTEM_MANDATORY_LABEL_NO_READ_UP` )

and point main - label [value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379602(v=vs.85).aspx) (sid):

handler thread always have **`"SI"`** - `SDDL_ML_SYSTEM` - System integrity level.

while usual threads have **`"ME"`** - `SDDL_MLMEDIUM` - Medium integrity level or

**`"HI"`** - `SDDL_ML_HIGH` - High integrity level, when run as admin

so - because this thread have higher integrity level ( System ) than usual process integrity level in token ( High integrity level or bellow, if not system process) and with no read and write up rights - we can not open this thread with read or write access, only with execute access.

---

we can do next test in `HandlerRoutine` - try open thread with `MAXIMUM_ALLOWED` and look for granted access with [`NtQueryObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryobject) ( use [`ObjectBasicInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ne-ntifs-_object_information_class) )

```
    if (HANDLE hThread = OpenThread(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, FALSE, GetCurrentThreadId()))
    {
        OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION obi;
        if (0 <= ZwQueryObject(hThread, ObjectBasicInformation, &obi, sizeof(obi), 0))
        {
            DbgPrint("[%08x]\n", obi.GrantedAccess);
        }
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
```

we got here: `[00101800]` which mean:

```
SYNCHRONIZE | THREAD_RESUME | THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION
```

also we can query [`ObjectTypeInformation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntifs/ne-ntifs-_object_information_class) and get [`GENERIC_MAPPING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446633(v=vs.85).aspx) for thread object.

```
        OBJECT_BASIC_INFORMATION obi;
        if (0 <= ZwQueryObject(hThread, ObjectBasicInformation, &obi, sizeof(obi), 0))
        {
            ULONG rcb, cb = (obi.TypeInfoSize + __alignof(OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION) - 1) & ~(__alignof(OBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION) - 1);
            POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION poti = (POBJECT_TYPE_INFORMATION)alloca(cb);
            if (0 <= ZwQueryObject(hThread, ObjectTypeInformation, poti, cb, &rcb))
            {
                DbgPrint("a=%08x\nr=%08x\nw=%08x\ne=%08x\n", 
                    poti->GenericMapping.GenericAll,
                    poti->GenericMapping.GenericRead,
                    poti->GenericMapping.GenericWrite,
                    poti->GenericMapping.GenericExecute);
            }
        }
```

and got

```
a=001fffff
r=00020048
w=00020437
e=00121800
```

so we in general can open this thread with `GenericExecute` access, except `00020000` (`READ_CONTROL`) because this access in GenericRead and GenericWrite and policy - no read/write up.

---

however for almost all api, where handle (thread or generic) required, we can use [`GetCurrentThread()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683182(v=vs.85).aspx) - pseudo handle for the calling thread. of course this can use only for current thread. so we can call for example

```
FILETIME CreationTime, ExitTime, KernelTime, UserTime;
GetThreadTimes(GetCurrentThread(), &CreationTime, &ExitTime, &KernelTime, &UserTime);
```

the `CloseHandle(GetCurrentThread());` also valid call - *Calling the CloseHandle function with this handle has no effect.* (simply nothing will be). and this pseudo handle have `GENERIC_ALL` granted access.

so your  `OpenThread` routine can check for thread id - if it is equal to `GetCurrentThreadId()` - simply return `GetCurrentThread()`.

also we can call

```
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), GetCurrentThread(), GetCurrentProcess(), &hThread, 0, 0, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
```

this also will be work well for this thread. however usual use `GetCurrentThread()` is enough

Answer (score 0):

So actually it turns out that there's a very specific set of conditions that means that a console can't get a handle to the thread in the thread itself - and that's when the thread is created in the console host to pass a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> notification to the console (the test conditions I was testing under)

Comment: Well, thread can open self in all other circumstances, except when it's the thread handling ctrl-c

Comment: can or can not be some thread(and any object) opened based only on 2 things - thread(object) security descriptor and thread (which try open) token. or process token, if running thread have no token.

Comment: of course can special set some process token (for example set low integrity for it). etc, which can prevent open threads in self process, but this is very special case

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Rather than post a speculative answer based on details not present in the question, I strongly urge you to remove the answer, and edit the question to include a [mcve]. Then there would be value.